# Comparing melting point of neopentane and butanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, melting-point

Why does something like 2,2-dimethylpropane have a much higher melting point than butan-1-ol?

I know that butan-1-ol has a hydroxyl group, and is capable of hydrogen bonding, and I know that 2,2-dimethylpropane is a compact symmetrical molecule, but I don't really see how shape and compatibility have such a huge factor on melting point compared to hydrogen bonding; or is this a special case?

Comment: Number of carbons is important too

Comment: Boiling points are subject to simple trends, but *melting points are tricky*.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65933/why-is-the-melting-point-of-tert-butyl-alcohol-140-c-higher-than-that-of-sec-bu https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92144/why-does-neopentane-have-a-higher-melting-point-than-n-pentane

Answer (score -2):

You are simply comparing the wrong compounds to see the effect of a hydroxyl group. Compare tertiary butyl alcohol to neopentane. While you are at it compare melting and  boiling points of the isomeric pentanes and butanols to get a general idea of the effects of molecular shapes.